# verify the digitally signed data with public key using RSA in iOS

Tags: ios, rsa, public-key-encryption

How to verify the digitally signed data with public key using RSA during decryption at device end. I don't want to use openssl.

Hoping for answer.

Comment: Cryptography algorithms can be very complex. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up using PGP. You can use RSA. Here is a link to read more about it if you did not know already. http://www.gnupg.org